# Facebook Pixel on different environments

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics, facebook-pixel

I have a FB pixel working properly, but still on development and staging environments.

What are the best practices to use this on production, should I always use at least two different pixels? in order to have reliable data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [some documentation on segment.com](https://segment.com/docs/destinations/facebook-pixel/) that recommends:

> We recommend setting up separate source for each environment. That way
>   you can either point events to test conversion pixels in Facebook
>   Conversion Tracking or turn off Facebook Conversion Tracking
>   completely in non-production environments.

Comment: Is the `source` a segment.com feature?  If so then I guess that the key take away is the idea of setting up two different facebook pixels, one that is used for dev/test environments and one for production.  I was kinda leaning this way anyway.  Was that your take?

Comment: I can't find any reference to `source` so am not sure. But I agree the key takeaway is to set-up a different pixel per environment.